# Some questions about Dotnetnuke

Tags: .net, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have got some questions about Dotnetnuke:

1. Can i create/run multiple websites having only VS 2010 installed or do i need IIS(Express) ?
2. Does a website create a physical map on your harddrive ?
3. Can DNN be seen as a SharePoint "alternative" ?
4. Once a site is in production can it handle a big workload ?

Thx for any answer.

Comment: VS comes with IIS express, IIS is requred to run wessites when you coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What I normally do is configure a local IIS (the real deal) to run the DNN installation (in C:\InetPub\yada...) and then create individual solutions in the DesktopModules folder for my custom modules.  I don't like loading the entire DNN site into VS unless I'm actually doing something directly to DNN.
2. Not sure what you mean by this question.  DNN does have a folder structure that is required for it to run.
3. I don't have a lot of SharePoint experience, but DNN is a pretty good content management system.  There are plenty of resources out there that cover this topic [such as this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/01/31/437023.aspx).
4. It depends on how well you configure caching and what custom "stuff" you have going on in the background.  This is like any web project, though.  www.dotnetnuke.com is a DotNetNuke installation and handles a pretty heft workload.  There are plenty of places to fine-tune your installation and so this shouldn't be a problem, depending on how you define a "big workload."

Comment: Thank you.

With question 2 i mean "When i create a new site/application, does dnn physically make a new website in my IIS" ?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of #1, you _can) use the built-in web server (Cassini) with Visual Studio, but you'll have to run the whole DNN website, not just the one module.  Like @James, we usually use IIS, it's simpler.